# Is there a way to tell which badges can be earned twice?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that some badges can be earned more than once, for example I have earned the Revival badge 3 times. But others I only have 1 of even though I have met the requirements that would be necessary to earn multiple. I've checked the descriptions on the Badges page to see if there is any indication of badges that can be earned more than once (or only once), but I don't see anything.

Is there a way to see what badges can be earned multiple times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On each badge there is an explanation on what needs to be fulfilled in order to earn the badge. After that one can see "This badge can be awarded multiple times." if it's possible to earn the badge more than once. As in [favorite-question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/favorite-question) or [guru](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guru).

Other badges, like [scholar](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scholar) doesn't have the multiple times notion after the explanation.

Unfortunately there is no filter for just showing multiple times badges.

Comment: Thanks Benny. I didn't think to actually click on the badges, so I didn't know the descriptions on the Badges page were not the full description.

Answer (score 1):

This information isn't available on the site's built-in badges list, but there is [a community-maintained list of badge details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) on the network meta that provides it.

(Full disclosure, on the off chance someone would find this objectionable: I posted the initial version of the linked post, years and years ago, before I was employed by Stack Exchange.)